# why az login stopped using browser and now uses "email and accounts". How to revert it?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I use `az login` for long time. It always showed Chrome browser for login. But now it uses "Email and accounts" windows feature.

When I execute `az login` the following popup window is shown:

[image: login popup window]

And the Task Manager shows "Emails and accounts" running:

[image: taks manager show emails and accounts]

It started behaving this way after executing `az account clear`, but I don't know if it is the cause.

Why it stopped showing browser?

And how can I revert it? I would like `az login` to show browser instead of email and accounts login popup.

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser Cache. Try setting your default broswer as Chrome and then check

Comment: @RithwikBojja. it doesn't help. Chome is the default browser

Comment: Try checking AZURE_CORE_NO_PAT_CACHE in environment variables if its 1 then change to 0

Comment: @RithwikBojja What is AZURE_CORE_NO_PAT_CACHE? I didn't find any maching documents https://www.google.com/search?q=AZURE_CORE_NO_PAT_CACHE

Comment: It sets the control of Azure CLI while authenticating with Azure

Answer (score 1):

When I use `az login` after using `az account clear` I am getting credentials default browser as below:

[image]

If you are not getting the same, As an alternative you can `use device code` attribute to login from browser want to use browser you can use the below code:

```
az login --use-device-code
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure CLI introduces a new signing method known as WAM, which I believe is enabled in your Azure CLI configuration.

You just need to disable it by running "az config set core.allow_broker=false"

Then

az account clear

az login